# Problem in Zipping a File

Tags: java, zip

When I run my code and use the files that are in the resource folder of my project itself, I face no problems. It zips the file successfully and I can extract it using WINZIP. The problem comes when I try to zip a file that is not in the project folder.

When I do the same, I am passing the Absolute Path of both the src and the dest files. My program doesn't give any exceptions, but when I try to open that zip file, I get an error saying, File is Invalid.

Can anyone tell me why this may be happening.

> public static void compress(String srcPath, String destPath) {

```
    srcFile = new File(srcPath);
    destFile = new File(destPath);
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        zipEntry = new ZipEntry(srcPath);
        zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] data = new byte[12];
        while ((fileInputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
            zipOutputStream.write(data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            fileInputStream.close();
        zipOutputStream.close();}catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which API? Code snippet?

Comment: Is this on Windows? Are you creating zip entries with drive letters e.g. `C:\path\file.txt`?

Comment: @dogbane: Yes, it is windows and I am creating zip entries with drive letters.

Comment: @Wivani: I am using java.util.zip.* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not store paths with drive letters in your zip file because when you try to extract your zip, it will try to create a directory with the name of the drive and fail.

You will need to change your code so that it removes the drive letter from the path before creating the `ZipEntry`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But why we have to remove the Drive Letter from the Path?

Comment: Try creating a directory called "C:". You will see that it is not allowed. In the same way, if you had drive letters in your zip and tried to extract it, it would fail.

Comment: Yes, its failing. But if I use 7zip to extract the file, its not failing. Instead, in the decompressed folder I see folders like D_ and then all inner folders.